# Does Python have a relational join operator?

Tags: python, join

I'm implementing the Apriori algorithm for frequent pattern mining. A key step of the algorithm is to generate candidate patterns by joining the current set of patterns to itself. For example, the set of itemsets

```
{[I1, I4], [I2, I4], [I2, I3], [I1, I3]}
```

Would generate the candidates,

```
{[I1, I3, I4], [I1, I2, I4], [I2, I3, I4], [I1, I2, I3]}
```

I don't want to bother with a SQL database or pandas DataFrames, because all I need are candidates from a set. I don't need to store other columns.

Matlab has a [join](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html) function that would perform this operation, but I can't figure out a solution for Python.

[SQL-like JOIN on two text files in Python, is there a built-in way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626619/sql-like-join-on-two-text-files-in-python-is-there-a-built-in-way) asks a similar question, but both solutions suggest using other tools, Unix tools and SQLite. Is Python simply the wrong language for the job?

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in operator. You can build a dict and write hash join behavior yourself, or, slightly trickier, write sort join code yourself. If you don't want to write algorithms like that, bare (pandas-less) Python probably is not what you want. I also don't know how big your dataset is, i.e., whether it's a problem to build a dictionary or sorted list in RAM.

Comment: @twotwotwo If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: should there not be a [I1, I2, I3] in the generated candidates

Comment: @Julius Good catch. I'll edit that

Comment: thanks for the matlab answer btw.

Comment: @Julius Thanks, and back at you. Thanks for your reciprocal answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using builtin sets (but not a builtin join method), if your I* objects have hash functions:

```
listOfSets = [set([1, 4]), set([2, 4]), set([2, 3]), set([1, 3])]

def selfJoin(l) : 
    ret = []
    for i, outer in enumerate(listOfSets):
        for inner in listOfSets[i + 1:]:
            inter = inner.intersection(outer)
            if len(inter) > 0 :
                ret.append(outer.union(inner))
    return ret

print(selfJoin(listOfSets))
```

prints

```
[{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Ref:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset